# Imagej how to get sum of area column in image j

Tags: macros, imagej

Currently have a results table from a pre selected ROI manager and would like to make it display the total area and max count. Having issues finding how to find sum since i cannot use `sum(`

```
//Checks to see if theyre previous measurements
if (roiManager("count") > 0)
{
    run("Clear Results");
}
roiManager("measure");
for (i = 0; i < nResults(); i++) {
// sets total area in results table
    a = getResult('Area', i);
// for b sums a
    for (b=0; i < nResults(); i++) {
        b+=a;
}
updateResults();
```

Ive tried running a function for the array but cannot seem to get it to find sum

Comment: run("Summarize"); gives you the basic statistics of table columns. However you may also use b+=a; in your loop, if you set b=0; before you enter the loop.

Comment: so run("summarize") only presents the mean, sd, min, and max for each column rather than a total sum of the column only

Comment: You have the number of entries with "nResults", i.e. you get the sum as: b=mean*nResults; — However, the alternative approach I've mentioned, works as well. Instead of "b=function sum(a)" (an operation that doesn't exist) you may write "b+=a;" but you need to add "b=0;" before the loop, i.e. before "for (...)".